# OpenCV translation vector in meters

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration, lidar

I have a calibrated (I know the intrinsic parameters) camera. Also, I have 2 photos of the object from this camera from different positions. In addition, I have synchronized data from the lidar of these two photos (distance in meters). A key step is to calculate translation vector in real-world coordinates (in meters).

At the moment I have already received the rotation matrix and translation vector using opencv [cv2.findEssentialMat](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga0b166d41926a7793ab1c351dbaa9ffd4) and [cv2.recoverPose](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga40919d0c7eaf77b0df67dd76d5d24fa1). And I don't have any ideas how to use depth data to resolve this scale ambiguity.

Thanks!

Comment: I would assume you have a set of matched points between the two images. How does your lidard data relate to those points? Does it provide distance for each point individually? A single measurement for all of them? ...

Comment: Use stereo calculations to estimate the 3D position of some points with your scale ambiguous relative external parameters. Then compare between the result and lidar data.
Now scale will be solved.